# Any example for combining geo location search query with distance filter/sorting?

Tags: go, sdk, couchbase, gocb

I am using gocb to query documents based on geo location . So far  `NewGeoDistanceQuery` works well with the index. Now i need to sort the result based on geo location distance . According to the doc in [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/fts/fts-geospatial-queries.html)  , it says i need to pass sort parameter inside the query! but the `NewGeoDistanceQuery` doesnt have that. So searched the sdk and found `NewSearchSortGeoDistance` that is exactly what i was looking for but I am confused on how to combine them.

```
    location := cbft.NewGeoDistanceQuery(in.Lat, in.Lon, fmt.Sprintf("%skm", in.Distance))
    sort := cbft.NewSearchSortGeoDistance("address", in.Lat, in.Lon).Unit("km")
    conjunctionQuery = cbft.NewConjunctionQuery(location, sort)
```

I tried the solution above but got this error

```
{"error":"rest_index: Query, indexName: restaurant-geo-search, err: bleve: QueryBleve parsing searchRequest, err: unknown query type","request":{"ctl":{"timeout":75000},"query":{"conjuncts":[{"distance":"2km","location":[90.404272,23.793993]},{"by":"geo_distance","field":"address","location":[90.404272,23.793993],"unit":"km"}]},"size":100},"status":"fail"}
```

I have also tried to use the `NewSearchSortGeoDistance` alone but same error. Any help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've answered at https://forums.couchbase.com/t/any-example-for-combining-geo-location-search-query-with-distance-filter-sorting/21155 but just to put all the info here too:

I think that the issue here is that you’re trying to use sort order as a query, rather than as sorting criteria. I think that what you want is probably `gocb.NewSearchQuery(indexName, location).Sort(sort)` . This will take the sort criteria and put it into the JSON request under the `sort` field, as you can see in our documentation.